# C# WPF application .NET 4.5 Set Mouse Position

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor-position

First time asking a question here, the solutions I found on here do not seem to work for some reason.  My app needs to set the mouse position when the window becomes active, I have the function set up but cannot get cursor properties to work.  I can't use Cursor.Position or anything really for some reason.  I had hoped to visit the chat rooms to find a solution but apparently I cannot speak until I have 20 reputation.

So here I am asking how to change the cursor position with something like

this.Cursor.SetPosition(x, y);

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Tried this already as a test from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position, 
   // and set its clipping rectangle to the form.  

   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

but the compiler complains about Current, Position, Clip, Location, Size

Final solution:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

...

Point relativePoint = MouseCaptureButton.TransformToAncestor(this)
                           .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
Point pt = new Point(relativePoint.X + MouseCaptureButton.ActualWidth / 2,
                     relativePoint.Y + MouseCaptureButton.ActualHeight / 2);
Point windowCenterPoint = pt;//new Point(125, 80);
Point centerPointRelativeToSCreen = this.PointToScreen(windowCenterPoint);
SetCursorPos((int)centerPointRelativeToSCreen.X, (int)centerPointRelativeToSCreen.Y);
```

Comment: Why do you ignore error messages. Compiler complains? Read error messages reproduce them.

Comment: Example: Error 1 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's in System.Windows.Forms. As documented.

Comment: My compiler does not recognize System.Windows.Forms Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well, that's because you won't reference winforms in a wpf app. Pinvoking SetCursorPos is a sound option.

Comment: Anyway, websearch helps. Try these search terms: *c# set cursor position wpf*

Comment: I am here from the future to say that this Stackoverflow is now the top hit on Google for searching how to move the mouse in C# WPF. Thank you very much for the helpful comments saying to Google the answer instead of providing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `InteropServices` to accomplish this fairly easily:

```
// Quick and dirty sample...
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetCursorPos(100, 100);
    }
}
```

Just make sure you include `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.  There are also a lot of other ways, such as the one pointed out in the duplicate link above.  Use what's best for you.

**EDIT:**

Per request in the comment, here's one way to make it an application window coordinate system, rather than a global one:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetCursor(200, 200);
    }

    private static void SetCursor(int x, int y)
    {
        // Left boundary
        var xL = (int)App.Current.MainWindow.Left;
        // Top boundary
        var yT = (int)App.Current.MainWindow.Top;

        SetCursorPos(x + xL, y + yT);
    }
}
```

I don't think you would do this... but just make sure that you don't try to get `Window` coordinates during the initialization phase (in the constructor).  Wait until it's loaded, similarly to how I've done above; otherwise, you may get `NaN` for some of the values.

If you want to restrict it to the confinements of the window, an easy way would be to add `System.Windows.Forms` to your references and use the code provided in the duplicate link.  However, if you want to use my method (all about personal preference... I use what I like... and I like `PInvoke`), you may check the `x` and `y` positions in `SetCursor(..)` prior to passing them to `SetCursorPos(..)`, similarly to this:

```
private static void SetCursor(int x, int y)
{
    // Left boundary
    var xL = (int)App.Current.MainWindow.Left;
    // Right boundary
    var xR = xL + (int)App.Current.MainWindow.Width;
    // Top boundary
    var yT = (int)App.Current.MainWindow.Top;
    // Bottom boundary
    var yB = yT + (int)App.Current.MainWindow.Height;

    x += xL;
    y += yT;

    if (x < xL)
    {
        x = xL;
    }
    else if (x > xR)
    {
        x = xR;
    }

    if (y < yT)
    {
        y = yT;
    }
    else if (y > yB)
    {
        y = yB;
    }

    SetCursorPos(x, y);
}
```

Note that you may want to account for the border if you application uses Windows look and feel.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I guess when I tried something similar to that from another answer they did not mention the required namespace.  I am used to Java in Eclipse which has an auto-import feature for their libraries.

Comment: @DeadJohnDoe Glad it helped, just... expand on my sample.  I would definitely not write it that way for production code.

Comment: So the cursor position that the above function uses is relevant to the computer's screen and not the program window?  Is there a way to use the program window's coordinate system instead?

Comment: @DeadJohnDoe See my edit, so that I wouldn't have to type a lot here.