# Remove highlight on button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As picture shows:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4XV2HrbrpDZX0xnZ1o1SHhiWm8/view?usp=drivesdk]

I would like to remove the highlight  after each click because I have set acceptbutton and ActiveControl to the "**equal**" button of this program
I want the operation of AcceptButton takes place instead of input the highlighted button text when I key press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard. Any idea? 
Thanks.

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @techydesigner what the code you means? I created this program, just want to know any method to remove the highlight

Comment: Surely there is something in the code that would affect it. It could be a glitch, but at least some of the code specific to the button could be helpful to other users.

Comment: @techydesigner By the question "Any idea?" I would guess that the `OP` is asking for ideas and not code writing as a service. The question does not require code in any way to be clear.

Comment: @LeandroTaset There may be something in the code affecting this. Either way, I don't know C# specifically so I will leave it to the experts.

Comment: @user6670219 You would have to play with all things that affect focus for a control. These are all good starting points: [Control.ShowFocusCues property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.showfocuscues.aspx), [Control.Focus() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) and [Control.SetStyle() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx).

Comment: Create a custom button deriving from `Button` and make it non-selectable in constructor: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` Like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10078372/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is duplicate of [How do I prevent WPF buttons from remaining highlighted after being clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950309/how-do-i-prevent-wpf-buttons-from-remaining-highlighted-after-being-clicked)

---

**Here is the solution:**

> What happens is that the button accepts the *input focus* after it has
>   been clicked, just like any other control does when you click on it.
>
> And the way that Windows indicates that a control has the input focus
>   (at least under the Aero theme) is with a subtle blue highlight.
>
> For a button control in particular, when it has the input focus,
>   simply pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will "push" that button.
>   That's why maintaining the highlight is very important, so that the
>   user knows what to expect.
>
> The better solution is to set the focus to a different control in your
>   window immediately after the user has clicked on the button. That way,
>   it will no longer be automatically highlighted and no action will be
>   automatically triggered when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   key. (This is the *real* usability problem that you're trying to
>   solve, even if you don't know it yet. Nothing is more confusing than a
>   button inadvertently getting clicked when the user is actually trying
>   to type something.)
>
> You *could* prevent the button from ever getting the focus altogether
>   by setting its [`Focusable` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.focusable.aspx) to false, but I would very
>   much recommend against this. Once you've done this, there will be no
>   way for the user to "press" the button using only the keyboard.
>   Well-designed applications should *always* be accessible to users who
>   either prefer not to or who are unable to use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you "*want the operation of `AcceptButton` takes place instead of input the highlighted button text when I key press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard.*",
one solution is to have the click handler for each button give focus to <kbd>=</kbd>.

Google "winforms control set focus" for code details.

This would preserve *accessibility*: keyboard-only users can <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the desired button, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "click" the button. Your click handler would then give focus to <kbd>=</kbd>, so it will be clear that *another* <kbd>Enter</kbd> would perform <kbd>=</kbd> action.

It also makes it clear to *any* user that they can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at any time, to get <kbd>=</kbd>.

On the other hand, it might be "disconcerting" to users to constantly see <kbd>=</kbd> get highlighted. Would require user-testing...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the buttons to flat:

```
btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

and then change the FlatAppearance:

```
btn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
btn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```